# Case Expression syntax in where clause makes problem that Sub query returned more than 1 value when the sub query is used as an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

[image: Here is my table recored]

I want to write some code that returns all table records if I select Branch code as empty.

But when I select Branch Code this should return the record only for specific Branch.

```
   declare 
   @BRANCHCODE varchar(4)
   set @BRANCHCODE=''
   if (@BRANCHCODE='')
   begin
    SELECT  ID,BRANCHCODE,BRANCHNAME,DEPARTMENTCODE,DEPARTMENTNAME FROM RATINGLOGS
   WHERE BRANCHCODE in (SELECT  BRANCHCODE FROM RATINGLOGS)
   end 
   else
   begin
    SELECT  ID,BRANCHCODE,BRANCHNAME,DEPARTMENTCODE,DEPARTMENTNAME FROM RATINGLOGS
   WHERE BRANCHCODE=@BRANCHCODE
   end
```

Above the code return fine.

Now I want to use this condition in case statement of where clause. Code is given below:

```
    declare 
   @BRANCHCODE varchar(4)
   set @BRANCHCODE=''
   SELECT  ID,BRANCHCODE,BRANCHNAME,DEPARTMENTCODE,DEPARTMENTNAME FROM RATINGLOGS
   WHERE BRANCHCODE in (Case when @BRANCHCODE='' then (SELECT  BRANCHCODE FROM RATINGLOGS) else  @BRANCHCODE  end)
```

It return fine when I set specific Branch Code . Such as

```
set @BRANCHCODE='1001'
```

But its return wrong:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

When I use

```
set @BRANCHCODE = ''
```

**It's mention that I use

```
BRANCHCODE in ()
```

such as it support more than 1 value. I don't use ( =, !=, <, <= , >, >=). But it's going wrong.**

I need the explanation of the question and if it possible using case statement in  where clause what the rewrite code will be?

Comment: I have used Sql-Server

Comment: In future please on tag the relevant database.

Comment: you subquery `in (Case when @BRANCHCODE` does not starts with `SELECT` Subquery must always be complete queries

Answer (score 1):

The `in` condition is redundant in the first query - the `branchcode` queried from `ratinglogs` must by definition be in the list of all the `branchcodes` selected from `ratinglogs`, so you can just drop the `where` clause there entirely.

Having that in mind, you can rewrite the query in the second snippet as so:

```
SELECT id, branchcode, branchname, depatmentcode, departmentname
FROM   ratinglogs
WHERE  @branchcode IN (branchcode, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `case` statement can only return 1 value, so when you use `...then (select branchcode from ratinglogs)`, it returns all of the values there, and this is an error.

If you want to combine the logic of the two queries into one, you have to use "case" logic but not the actual `case` statement:

```
WHERE (
(@BRANCHCODE='' and BRANCHCODE in (SELECT  BRANCHCODE FROM RATINGLOGS))
or
(not @BRANCHCODE='' and BRANCHCODE=@BRANCHCODE)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to the `IN()` operator there, your query can be like

```
SELECT ID,
       BRANCHCODE,
       BRANCHNAME,
       DEPARTMENTCODE,
       DEPARTMENTNAME 
FROM RATINGLOGS
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN @BRANCHCODE = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END --@BRANCHCODE = ''
      OR
      BRANCHCODE = @BRANCHCODE;
```

The above code will returns all rows if `@BRANCHCODE = ''`, and if it hold another value, it will returns the specific row where `BRANCHCODE = @BRANCHCODE`.

Since you're asking about the `CASE` expression, if you want to use `IN()` operator you can use the other solution by *@Mureinik*.

If the variable `@BRANCHCODE` can hold multiple values eg: `'1001,1002,1003'` then it won't work as you expect, you will need to split the string to rows.

```
SELECT ID,
       BRANCHCODE,
       BRANCHNAME,
       DEPARTMENTCODE,
       DEPARTMENTNAME 
FROM RATINGLOGS
WHERE BRANCHCODE = ''
      OR
      BRANCHCODE IN (SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@BRANCHCODE, ','));
```

note that **[`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function is only available in SQL Server 2016+ versions, if you don't have you need to define your own

Answer (score 0):

you dont need any subquery

```
SELECT  ID,
        BRANCHCODE,
        BRANCHNAME,
        DEPARTMENTCODE,
        DEPARTMENTNAME 
FROM    RATINGLOGS
WHERE   (@BRANCHCODE = '' or BRANCHCODE = @BRANCHCODE)
```

This will return all rows if the variable @BRANCHCODE = '' and otherwise it will only return rows where BRANCHCODE = @BRANCHCODE

Since you declared @BRANCHCODE only as varchar(4) I assume it will always only hold one value.
If you need it to hold more than one code, than this wont work